# How do I get outputs in Ruby using SWIG over a C function taking pointers to output arguments?

Tags: c++, ruby, swig

How do I get outputs (declared using int pointers) from a function I wrote in C++, using SWIG, in Ruby? In the transcript below, I'm declaring an 'a' and a 'b' just to get them initialized as integers, but really they're supposed to be outputs.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'vetms.rb'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> a=3
=> 3
irb(main):003:0> b=4
=> 4
irb(main):004:0> $v.button a, b
ArgumentError: Wrong arguments for overloaded method 'BaseInterface.button'.
Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
bool BaseInterface.button(int *id, int *event)
bool BaseInterface.button(int *id)
bool BaseInterface.button()

    from (irb):4:in `button'
    from (irb):4
    from :0
```

(Edit) The SWIG code isn't remarkable--I do use **%include 'pointers.i'** but I'm not sure what I get with that. 'vetms.rb' simply requires the generated library and creates a $v object. My main problem here is with my C++ function, which Ruby can't bind my 'a' and 'b' objects to:

```
bool BaseInterface.button(int *id, int *event)
```

My problem is, If I were doing this in straight C, I would pass the address of 'a' and 'b' to the function, and the function would set the contents--'a' and 'b' are output variables. So I'd like the call to '$v.button a, b' to do the same thing. Now I'm not sure passing variables by reference or address is even a concept in Ruby, I just need two outputs from that call, and I don't know how to achieve it.

The SWIG docs suggest that you can have such a function (this is in "SWIG and Ruby", section 32.3.5 Pointers):

```
Foo *get_foo();
void set_foo(Foo *foo);
```

But they only provide one usage example, for the return value:

```
irb(main):001:0> foo = Example::get_foo()
#<SWIG::TYPE_p_Foo:0x402b1654>
```

In this case, how does one use "set_foo" in Ruby?

I'll look into FFI, but does anybody know how to do this with SWIG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to comment without the SWIG / vetms.rb code.  Guessing you need to do some work with a typemaps.

I'd suggest using FFI instead of SWIG to interface your C code

https://github.com/ffi/ffi

much easier, and nicer

Comment: OK, I found the specific answer, and it's pretty simple. I put this line in my .i file: "%apply int *OUTPUT { int *id, int *event }". This apparently tells SWIG to generate a wrapper that returns those values, so the Ruby line now looks like this: "f, a, b = $v.buttons", where f is now the "bool" return value of the C++ function, and 'a' and 'b' are the output parameters. I'll give you the "correct answer" flag since you suggested I look closer into typemaps.